# How content from layout_update table is set?

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I have a row in the `layout_update` table that adds element to pages. I'd like to know how [some xml] from this row was set in the backed:

```
id  | handle  | xml        | sort_order | updated_at
194 | default | [some xml] | 1          | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Can it be edited in backend or do I need to do this directly in the db?